# Controlling an analog potentiometer using an Arduino

Tags: servo, potentiometer

I want to be able to control an analog potentiometer. I'd like to be able to go from the minimum range to the maximum range possibly using an Arduino and a motor/servo. I want to be able to control vintage equipment, so the knobs on the pot must still work. I want to be able to rotate both by hand and by sending  a (MIDI) signal.How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Arduino StackExchange! Just a small question, why not just use a digital potentiometer?

Comment: I want to be able to control  vintage equipment, so the knobs on the pot must still work. I want to be able to rotate both by hand and by sending  a (MIDI) signal.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is a motorized fader.

Comment: Can you replace the original potentiometer? Can you drill holes for attaching a servo?

Comment: Ideally I'd like to use the original pot and have the servo/whatever the solution is inside the case so that you can't tell a mod was made.

Comment: Add a pulley wheel to the shaft of the pot and drive it with a DC motor and a rubber belt? Like a belt drive from an old tape deck. You may be able to fit it on the inside of the housing.

Comment: Like [this](https://www.waste.org/~knobs/arduino_remote_stereo_volume_control.html) but with the gubbins on the inside of the case, not the outside.

Comment: That works, but I would need it on multiple pots and on the inside. Maybe I'm looking for motorized potentiometers?

Answer (score 1):

The first problem we have is that replacing the original potentiometer might be wrong thing to do. Analog audio hardware is usually nonlinear, because the volume of the sound is actually a logarithmic function. So the potentiometers might be fine tuned specifically for particular device, and impossible to acquire today since it's vintage.

I suggest a different approach. Connect the knobs to rotary encoders, or cheap linear potentiometers. That way you will receive data about what the user is doing, and what setting does he want to change. They usually are small and you might even fit an extra el-cheapo 28BYJ485V stepper motor to move the knobs to provide feedback. (It can be modified doubling it's torque)

Move all the audio potentiometers inside the case of the device and connect them directly to a stepper motor or a servo to move them only with Arduino.